# What is the maximum number of heart containers I can have?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In Zelda games the maximum is normally 20, however due to the Life Medals I'm uncertain if this holds true. Futhermore, if the maximum is 20, is that with or without Life Medals?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 20

This includes:

- 6 that you start with
- 6 from the Pieces of Heart (there are 24, and you need 4 to make a full heart container)
- 2 from the Life Medals
- 6 from the bosses in the game. (Demon Lord Ghirahim, Pyroclastic Fiend Scaldera, Thousand-Year Arachnid Moldarach, Ancient Automaton Koloktos, Abysmal Leviathan Tentalus,  and the second fight with Demon Lord Ghirahim all reward you with a heart container after you defeat them.)

(Source: [Heart Container Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/faqs/63387), and [Bosses](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-walkthrough.php))

Comment: That adds up to 22.

Comment: Huh, so it does. Somewhere either my math is wrong (more than likely) or my source info is wrong.

Comment: @AshleyNunn It's possible that you simply can't go beyond 20 heart containers, and life medals are unable to boost you above 20.

Comment: There are only six Heart Containers gotten from bosses — one from each of the main dungeons. Neither of your source links mentions the idea that eight bosses give Heart Containers; I think you just assumed that there would be 20 regular Heart Containers, just like all the other console Zelda games.

Comment: Yeah, I just made a mistake there. I have updated my answer to show where the boss heart containers come from.